# Compressing content in Java without file I/O

Tags: java, compression

I would like to perform repeated compression task for CPU profiling without doing any file I/O but strictly reading a byte stream. I want to do this in Java (target of my benchmark).

Does anyone have a suggestion how to do this?
I used Zip API that uses ZipEntry but ZipEntry triggers file I/O.

Any suggestions or code samples are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I used Zip API that uses ZipEntry but ZipEntry triggers file I/O.

I wouldn't expect it to if you use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as the underlying output:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
... write to zipStream ...
```

Likewise wrap your byte array for *reading* data from in a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Of course, `ZipOutputStream` is appropriate if you want to create content using the zip compression format, which is good for (or at least handles :) multiple files. For a *single* stream of data, you may want to use [`DeflaterOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html) or [`GZIPOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html), again using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as the underlying output.

Comment: I have found this example, http://piotrga.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/howto-compress-or-decompress-byte-array-in-java/ which uses GZIPOutputStream to probably be sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: @Edmon: Just don't copy the exception handling "techniques" from that code. You should be using `finally` blocks for `close()` calls, and probably just declaring that your method can throw `IOException`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a FileInputStream or FileOutputStream you can use ByteArrayInputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream.